# Cannot delete invisible files on OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have no items on my desktop in finder. When I enter the "ls" command in terminal at my desktop, two mysterious invisible files pop up:

```
~$Revised_December_EOM_Report-2.xlsx
~$Revised December EOM Report-2.xlsx
```

I've tried "sudo rm -rf "(both file names)", but still can't seem to remove them. I tried with and without quotes. I also tried the names without the ~$ prefix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` sign:

```
rm ~\$Revised_December_EOM_Report-2.xlsx
```

---

Alternatively, enable displaying hidden files in Finder by editing its `defaults` and delete from the GUI.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```