# ls shows file, ls -la not

Tags: macos

I have a strange issue on a Mac OS X 10.8.0.

With `ls`, I'm able to see a file, but not with `ls -la`:

```
me@machost$ ls
file.txt
```

And with `ls -la`:

```
me@machost$ ls -la
ls: file.txt: No such file or directory
total 64
drwxrwxr-x  2 _www  mygroup  2048 Nov  2 08:23 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 _www  mygroup  2048 Nov  2 09:01 ..
```

Does anyone have an idea whats happening here?

Comment: What does `file file.txt` output?

Comment: me@machost$ file file.txt
file.txt: cannot open `file.txt' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Sorry, browser spammed that comment. Can you see it in a GUI file browser at all?

Comment: I can see it in the Finder, although I can't see the size, and created/modified/last opened attributes.

Comment: It sounds like the ghost of a file, or a very oblique dangling symlink. I'm guessing rm will have none of it to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a corrupted directory entry for a deleted inode? ls finds the directory entry but ls -l cannot locate the inode to get the additional information.

I'd try [checking the filesystem](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1417)

See also [Cannot delete invisible files on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/233821/cannot-delete-invisible-files-on-osx)